# Why won't my service register?

Tags: angularjs

I tried creating a service in angularjs but I keep getting angular.js:10467 Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'MainController' is not a function, got undefined.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">

<form name="searchUser" method="post">
    <input ng-model="username" type="search" placeholder="Find"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)" />
</form>
You are searching for:  {{username}}


<hr />
    <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">

        {{ key + " :  " + value}}
    </div>



</div>

<script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="services/Screamer.js"></script>
```

my app.js:

```
angular.module('NoteTaker', []);  // dependcies in array.


angular.module('NoteTaker', []).controller('MainController', function(screamer, $log, $http, $scope, $interval){
    $http({
        method : 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + $scope.username
    }).then(function(response){
        console.log(response);
        $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```

my service  in service.js

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('NoteTaker', []).factory('screamer', function(){
        return {
                say: "blahbalh"
        };
    });
}());
```

Answer (score 5):

`angular.module(name, dependencies)` creates a *new* module. If you want to add to an existing one, use `angular.module(name)`:

```js
angular.module('NoteTaker', []); // dependcies in array.

angular.module('NoteTaker')
  .controller('MainController', function(screamer, $log, $http, $scope, $interval) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + $scope.username
    }).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      $scope.data = response.data;
    }, function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    });
  });

// service.js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('NoteTaker').factory('screamer', function() {
    return {
      say: "blahbalh"
    };
  });
}());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="NoteTaker" ng-controller="MainController">

  <form name="searchUser" method="post">
    <input ng-model="username" type="search" placeholder="Find" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" ng-click="search(username)" />
  </form>
  You are searching for: {{username}}


  <hr />
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in data">

    {{ key + " : " + value}}
  </div>



</div>
```

I create a new module on line 1, and add the controller & service to it.

Comment: in screamer, how would i get access to the $http service then?

Comment: @runners3431 Just add it to the function parameters, like everything else? `.factory('screamer', function($http) {...`

Answer (score 0):

tcooc answered your question, but I'll try to make it a little easier to understand:

```
app.module('myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2']);  // passing an array creates a NEW module
```

Access the newly created module by calling the same method, but without the array of dependencies:

```
app.module('myModule') 
  .controller('MyController')
  .service('MyService')
  .factory('MyFactory');
```

Or, just attach everything to the first module call:

```
app.module('myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2'])
  .controller('MyController', function(...) {})
  .service('MyService', function(...) {})
  .factory('MyFactory', function(...) {});
```

Also, it helps to write dependency injection like this:

```
MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$location', '$log'];
function MyController($scope, $location, $log) { 
}

MyService.$inject = ['$http'];
function MyService($http) {
}
```

This makes it clear what is getting injected where. And it makes your code much more readable, since you can now write this:

```
app.module('myModule', ['dep1', 'dep2'])
  .controller('MyController', MyController)
  .service('MyService', MyService);
```